# Is there a way to define unusual integer sizes in C++?

Tags: c++

I can define values of an integer of different sizes in C++ using: `std::int8_t`, `std::uint32_t`, etc. Is there a way to define an integer that uses, say 14 bits?

Comment: `std::int16_t` can hold at least 14 bits. Why do you need it *not* to hold those two extra bits?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/c-c-force-bit-field-order-and-alignment

Comment: No, you can provide a class behaving as int14, only.

Comment: @KeithThompson For compiling to specialized hardware that supports weird sizes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679801/custom-byte-size

Comment: ["The integers of unusual size? I don't think they exist."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Bride)

Comment: @oconnor0 If you´re compiling for unusual HW, `int` will be already how it should be on the HW. Your task is not to write a different integer type, but to make sure your code works with different `int`

Comment: @deviantfan The hardware supports regular ints and weird ints.

Comment: What hardware is it?

Comment: This is at least the 4th time I see such questions this year....

Comment: @oconnor0 That´s fine, but nonetheless it makes no sense to write some int-emulating classes if you really want that weird hardware int.

Comment: If some specialized hardware supports 14-bit integers, I'd expect a compiler for such hardware to support their use somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Read all the comments and other answers for clarification on why.

Answer (score 3):

Is bitfield what you are looking for?
In this example y takes 14 bits It's the closest match I can think of

```
struct x
{
    int y :14 ;
} ;
```

Comment: In C, a bit field of type `int` may be either signed or unsigned; it's implementation-defined. I don't know whether the same rule applies to C++. In any case, explicitly using `signed int` or `unsigned int` isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that behaves exactly like std::uint14_t would behave if it existed. Since any values that don't fit with signed types invoke undefined behaviour, typedef std::int16_t int14_t is a perfectly fine.

Comment: Not exactly, because `uintN_t` is defined as containing no padding bits, but this class would have to contain padding bits.

Comment: So just call it `uint_least14_t`.